# Trying to make a cleaner async JSON translations call

Tags: javascript, frontend

I'm trying to get translations from a JSON file, and have a function handling if the the JSON path is wrong.

I really want to have all the logic in one file so I can call my translations like this `Tr('website.basket.heading')`, from any other file.

I've almost accomplished this with a promise and await, but I would still like to make it cleaner.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm trying to run something async from a sync function, if I remove await that is. 
I have also tried to make a global event, but then I will have to inset event listeners in function which uses the translations, still not as clean as just calling the `Tr()` function.

Here is an example of my working script with await, and this is the way i would like to go, just without the await https://codepen.io/Vohtz/pen/VEGXKv.

But can someone help me figure out how to call call `Tr()` without await? Or any ideas if I can go in a totally different direction?

Comment: without await you aren't awaiting so the logic is all different

Comment: but here is someFunction without await ... `Tr('website.basket.heading').then(translation => document.getElementById('elm').innerHTML = translation);` done

Comment: you also don't need to tag `Tr` with `async` ... since you never need to `await` in that function

Comment: I see what you're trying to do ... you're trying to trick asynchrony into being synchronous - you can't do that

Comment: Here's a simplified version of your code - https://pastebin.com/g2XY4F9n no `async`/`await` - here's a greatly simplified version https://pastebin.com/ZH2uBWcr - also with no `async`/`await`

Comment: Jaromanda X, you are totally right about me trying to trick asynchrony into being synchronous. I don't think I am better off with Tr().then() than await, but i really liked what you did with the simplified version ;-).
I have been talking with the backenders and I think we will be going a different way.